# sas format variable with custom date format - how to retain formatting?

Tags: sas, format, sas-macro

```
/*Create datetime format for db*/

proc format;
picture dbdate
    other = '%Y-%0m-%0d-%0H.%0M.%0S' (datatype=datetime);
run;

/*Create variable that is 24 hours ago*/

data _null_;
sdt = intnx("HOUR",datetime(),-1,"SAME");
format sdt dbdate.;
call symput ('sdt',sdt);
run;

%put &sdt;
```

when run the put sdt; return 2020-02-21-09.28.28 correctly, but when calling sdt later it %put &sdt; it returns the unformated value  Macro variable SDT resolves to   1897896509

how do i get sdt to retain its format or do i need to keep using format sdt dbdate. somehow everytim i call the variable?

Thanks

here the later proc sql step where i need to use the sdt variable in the dbdate. format:

```
proc sql;
connect to db (database=bob user="&srvuser" password="&srvpass") ;
create table ted as 
select * from connection to db
(Select *
        from work 
        where num = 7387 and ADD_TMSTMP < &sdt);
disconnect from db;
quit;
run;
```

Comment: A macro variable does not have a format. If you want to put the formated value in the log, simply use the Put Statement inside the Data Step.

Comment: Thanks, i need to be able to use the formated sdt variable later in a proc sql where timstamp < sdt step? added sample proc sql step to question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pass through SQL requires a date value represented by the form rendered by your custom picture format.  Send that rendering to the macro variable, not the underlying value.

```
call symput ('sdt',put(sdt,dbdate.));
```

You could eliminate your DATA step prior to the SQL if you coded

```
proc sql;
connect to db (database=bob user="&srvuser" password="&srvpass") ;
create table ted as 
select * from connection to db
(Select *
        from work 
        where num = 7387 
        and
          ADD_TMSTMP 
          <

          %sysfunc(intnx(HOUR,%sysfunc(datetime()),-1,SAME),dbdate.)
);
disconnect from db;
quit;
run;
```

If the pass through SQL needs a single quoted date representation, such as `'2020-02-21-06.06.36'` you will need to update your custom format to include the bounding single quotes.

```
proc format;
  picture dbdate
    other = '''%Y-%0m-%0d-%0H.%0M.%0S''' (datatype=datetime);
run;
```